# What is the best way to say and use commas in "Missing items in, or damages to, your room"?

Tags: commas

> If there are **missing items in, or damages to, your room** at the start of the year, you may incur a fine.

My question is about whether or not there is a grammatical term or rule for what I'm trying to do here. If there is, I want to know whether or not I am following it.

Forgive me if the question is ambiguous — I don't know the words used to describe the things I'm curious about.

Comment: If the items are missing, then they're not "in" your room.  The only way missing items would be in your room is if they were missing from someplace else, like if you had stolen them and hidden them in your room.

Comment: The best way is to reword it.  "If, at the start of the year, items are missing from your room, or the room is damaged in some way, you may be subject to a fine."

Comment: It's an RNR construction, standing for "right node raising".

Comment: @GregLee - So now are you going to write an answer where you explain the term?

Comment: @aparente001, I thought anyone interested would look it up.  But, in case you can't google, here's an account: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right_node_raising

Comment: @BenjaminHarman *in* it is in the context. Think again.

Comment: @GregLee - Is there some reason you don't want to write an answer?

Comment: @aparente001, yes.  It's not a good use of my time.  I reviewed the Wikipedia entry, and it is good.  Look there.

Comment: Thanks for the help, everyone! Despite my question's title, I suppose I'm not actually concerned with the sentence itself. I'm interested in the construction. "The story of what happened to, and within, that train is remarkable," would also be a sufficient example. It appears this is called right node raising, which is helpful to know. Should I try the linguistics stackexchange to learn more about how or how not to use RNR?

Answer (score -1):

Your sentence looks fine. The general rule is that the sentence should make sense if you remove the parenthetical clause, e.g.

> If there are missing items in your room at the start of the year, you may incur a fine.

and the parenthetical clause should parallel the item before it, so you could interchange them.

> If there are damages to, or missing items in, your room at the start of the year, you may incur a fine.

This seems like it may be an example of [*right node raising*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right_node_raising), where parallel structures in the sentence share the rest of the sentence. None of the examples on the Wikipedia page have commas setting off the parallel structures, though. It may be optional, but it feels more appropriate when the parallel structures end with prepositions (which is necessary here because the prepositions are different).

Not related to the comma question, the appropriate preposition to use with "missing" in this context would be "from", not "in". Also, I would expect the fine to be incurred at the *end* of the year, not the beginning.

Comment: I myself didn't downvote, but I do have some feedback.  OP wants to know what to call the thing with the commas.

Comment: See my comment at Benjamin above.

Comment: @aparente001 I'm not one of the grammaticists who knows all the technical terms, just a layman who believes he has a good command of the language as spoken. The problem with asking two questions at once is that you may only get an answer to one of them, and that's what I did.

Comment: @Barmar - Do you want to flesh out your answer using Greg's link?

Comment: @aparente001 I added the reference, although for some reason this feels a little different from the examples there.

Comment: I came across an article with a bunch of examples.  I found this page easier to understand than the wikipedia page.  https://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=38840 -- see what you think.  (I think you should include at least one example in your answer.)